# Node javascript - how to take two user input values in a single line in CLI?

Tags: javascript

I need to take two user inputs on the **same line** in the command prompt, so i can use them as variables (first value as a .txt file and the second value is an integer). How do i go about doing this?

Additionally:  how do you limit the number of printlines based on a `forEach` function as provided:  `frs.forEach(kc => console.log(kc[0].toString(), kc[1]))`
lets say the user inputs the value 3 and i only want the `forEach` function to print at max 3 lines and not the entire thing.

How do i also go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a library like [Yargs](http://yargs.js.org/). You can setup all kinds of command line stuff.  I have only used it a couple times, but have found it pretty great.

In the `forEach`, if I wanted to only print the first two arguments I would do something like this:

```
array.forEach((element, index) => {
  if (index === 0) console.log(element.toString())
  if (index === 1) console.log(element)
})
```